# How to translate this python code into a flowchart

Tags: python, flowchart

Im having trouble converting this piece of code into a flowchart. If you could give me hints or even do it for me that would be great (with explanations of course)

```
list = ['Yes','yes','YES','y','Y','NO','No','no','n','N'] 
list1 = ['Yes','yes','YES','y','Y']
list2 = ['NO','No','no','n','N']
class TS: 
    def DM4(self):
        a = input('Do you have problems with your memory managment?') 
        if a not in list: 
            objTS = TS() 
            objTS.DM4() 
        elif a in list1: 
            f = open('dm4.txt', 'r') 
            print(f.read()) 
        elif a in list2:
            objTS = TS()
            objTS.Menu()
    def Menu(self):
        userMenuOpt = input("""******************************************
Welcome to the trobule shooter 
Choose a category from the option below:
Hardware
Device Managment
Media & Internet
Not Sure
******************************************`
""")
        if userMenuOpt in ["Device Management","DM","devicemanagment","dm","DEVICE MANAGEMENT"]:
            objTS = TS()
            objTS.DM4()
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone will do this for you. I will try to offer some hints.

1. First you need to find a starting point

   1. In your example there really is no starting point as you only define some variables and a class.
   2. In Python for a script such as yours the starting point is usually at the bottom of the script in a block protected by `if __name__ == "__main__":`
2. Once you have your starting point you need to look at the flow control pieces of your program like loops and conditionals
3. You would normally look for "code paths" that you would like to document as usually every possible "code path" isn't documented in a flow chart (although they can be), but usually you would look at a task the user is trying to accomplish and draw his progress as it relates to the flow control mechanisms in your code
4. If you don't already know the standard symbols used in a flow chart you would usually start with a [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=flow+chart+symbols&t=ffsb) to learn which symbols are used and what they mean
5. If you find your flow chart becoming too large or complex, you may think about breaking it out into multiple flow charts each covering a separate process or perhaps a high-level flow chart supplemented by more detailed charts explaining the low-level details.
6. If all of this sounds too intimidating, you may have some luck farming out the work (there are many websites out there for this and as I am not affiliated with any of them I won't offer a suggestion)

I hope this helped.